# How to populate JSON response values in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I got the result of a Ajax call in JSON array format, like this

```
var productList ={
"products": [
    {
        "brandName": "B1",
        "productID": "Pid1",
        "productName": "P1",
        "imagePath": "IP1",
        "mrp price": "9.99",
        "sell price": "8.99"
    },
    {
        "brandName": "B1",
        "productID": "Pid3",
        "productName": "P2",
        "imagePath": "IP2",
        "mrp price": "19.99",
        "sell price": "18.99"
    },
    {
        "brandName": "B1",
        "productID": "Pid3",
        "productName": "P4",
        "imagePath": "IP1",
        "mrp price": "29.99",
        "sell price": "558.99"
    }
]
};
```

Now in success function of ajax call, i want to create the `<li> .. </li>` elements for each
product available in JSON response. I want to apply some CSS classes and Ids to elements. This is the format for li.

```
<li class='productWrap $productID' style='height:200px; width:150px;'>
<center> 
    <div class=\"productImageWrap\" id=\"productImageWrapID_+$productID\">
        <img src=$imagePath width='75' height='75' />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div style='font-size: 11px; font-family: \"Verdana\"; '> 
            $brandName + " " + $productName 
        </div>
        <b>                             
            <span>  
                <strike>   $mrp price  </strike>    
                $sell price 
            </span>
            <a href='#' id=\"featuredProduct_$data[0]\" onclick=\" adjust_menu(this.id); simpleCart.add('name=$brandName + " " + $productName', 'price=$sell price','image=$imagePath');             return false;\">   
                <img src='images/add-to-basket2.gif' alt='Add To Basket' width='111' height='32' id='featuredProduct_+$productID' />
            </a>
        </b>
    </div>
</center>
</li>
```

My doubt is How to populate these values in Ajax success function. The values that i need to populate is shown as $ prefix like $brandName $productName  etc.

I not only want to fill these values to display but want to fill in such a way that i can access any element after filled-up (using CSS class and IDs that we are applying while populating) to use for Jquery click and Mouse Hover functions.

Comment: is this whole html is writing from jQuery?

Comment: Yes. Initially i was returning the complete HTML from Perl script itself after filling the values. Now i want to do it on Client side.

Comment: so your ajax request is success and getting values in client side, but its not displaying while you writing it as html.. rite?

Comment: Its displaying the values also. But I don't want to return HTML things from PERL script, That's why now Perl will return only DATA in JSON format. and at client side we do all the logic to display it in proper format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
   success: function(data){
         $ul = $('#theUl');
         data.products.each(function(){
             var li = "<li><h1 class='name'>"+this.brandName+" "+this.productName+"</h1></li>";
             $ul.append(li);
         });

   }
```

additionaly, if you want to have a click-event on h1.name you have to delegate the selector, because you push it into the DOM way after it is ready. That could look like :

```
$(document).on("click",".name",function(){
  alert('Yeah i successfully bound an event with an element that did not exist initially')
});
```